# WPF Avoid the size of the (main)window to be smaller than the content

Tags: c#, wpf, resize, window-resize

I have created a simple WPF application with following XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button MinWidth="200" MinHeight="40" Content="Hello 1"/>
    <Button MinWidth="200" MinHeight="40" Content="Hello 2" Grid.Column="1"/>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

If I start the application I can resize the windows to a smaller size than the two buttons.

As you can see I have used the MinWidth and MinHeight properties, but they didn't work.

Please help me in this case.

Regards,

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

You probably already solved your problem but I'll leave a simple solution for anyone who is still new to WPF (like me).

Inside the `<Window>` tag, add an event handler to the `ContentRendered` event:

```
<Window x:Class="MyTest.MyForm" 
    ... 
    ... 
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
    ContentRendered="Window_ContentRendered">`
```

Then add the code-behind:

```
private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MinWidth = ActualWidth;
    MinHeight = ActualHeight;
}
```

This way, the window will calculate its size first (based on `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"`), then you set the minimum values after it renders its content, thus preventing the user from resizing it to be smaller than the content.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to add MinHeight and MinWidth to the WINDOW level to never go smaller than the smallest elements you are expecting WITHIN its content...

Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" MinHeight="90" MinWidth="410" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"

two buttons high of 40 (80) Plus some arbitrary gap (10) = min height of 90... Likewise for the width.  Two buttons minimum width of 200 = 400 total plus arbitrary gap (10) = 410.

Comment: Yes. This should work. But what can I do if the content has a dynamical behaviour? In this example the width and the height of the button could change with a trigger event (= An animation changes with a click on a button the width and the heigth).

Comment: What I mean is how can I change the min height and width of the "Window" depending on the dynamic change of the content (And of course I don't know the width and heigth of the content at the start of the application?)